# Azure Pipelines GitHub building branches

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

We are trying out Azure Pipelines CI with a GitHub project now that it is available in the marketplace. I've noticed that it doesn't seem to build branches besides master. Their documentation states that if a `trigger` section is specified in `azure-pipelines.yml` that you can configure it to *only* build specific branches, but that if `trigger` is not specified that it should be triggering off of all branches.

When I make changes to other branches besides master they do not trigger a build. Anybody know why, or is this a bug?

Comment: Can you share the yml file?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set in your `azure-pipelines.yml` file?

Test with GitHub follow the sample mentioned here : [Continuous integration (CI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#continuous-integration-ci) and everything works as expected.

e.g,:

```
name: My Cool Build
trigger:
```

It will trigger the build once changes applied to any branch...

Comment: Adding an empty trigger block to my azure pipelines file like that results in a failed build.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the examples are not clear.  Try this example and it should work to build ALL branches:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/heads/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: ['*']
```

As reported in the comments in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#continuous-integration-ci) (not the docs themselves obvs)